# Does the @inline annotation in Scala really help performance?

Tags: performance, scala, scala-2.8

Or does it just clutter up the code for something the JIT would take care of automatically anyway?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I have yet to find a case where it improves performance, and I've tried in quite a few different spots.  The JVM seems to be quite good at inlining when it's possible, and even if you ask for @inline in Scala, it can't always do it (and sometimes I've noticed that it doesn't even when I think it ought to be able to).

The place where you expect to see a bytecode difference is in something like this:

```
object InlineExample {
  final class C(val i: Int) {
    @inline def t2 = i*2
    @inline def t4 = t2*2
  }
  final class D(val i: Int) {
    def t2 = i*2
    def t4 = t2*2
  }
}
```

when compiled with `-optimise`.  And you do see the difference, but it generally doesn't run any faster since the JIT compiler can notice that the same optimizations apply to `D`.

So it may be worth a try in the final stages of optimization, but I wouldn't bother doing it routinely without checking to see if it makes a difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks for reporting your test results; saved me and probably others some time :)

Comment: You argument is only true if there was only one JIT compiler on the planet. — But this is not true. There is Android, there is IBM which produces there own JVMs. So anything the Scala compiler does *for sure* is better then something some JIT *might* do.

Comment: @Martin - I admit that haven't tried Android.  I've tried JRockit and the IBM JVM with the same effect as the Sun JVM (i.e. none).

Comment: I still have a question open. Does the @inline at least tell me that a method can reliably be inlined from the jit? So that i can use it to get compile time informations of runtime optimizations. And what about non HotSpot Jvm? How does it perform on Android.

Comment: @Arne - Inline tells the Scala compiler to try to inline the method.  It doesn't know what the JVM may or may not do.  Dalvik inlines getters/setters but not much else as I understand it, so it's worth testing for improvements with inline there.

Comment: I've had some luck recently using inline. ~15% performance increase for a heavily used function.

Comment: 2.10.2 -- I realize this is an old answer, but I figured I would comment.

Comment: @WesFreeman, based on this experience how would you describe a (potentially) effective use of inline?

Comment: In Kotlin inlining also exists. It is also used for things beyong performance improvements such as implementing non-local returns, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html That non-local returns are discontinued in Scala 3 is something that really bothers me. It could be implemented in Scala 3 as well just as in Kotlin.