# Requesting more information about @inline from the compiler?

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, annotations, inline, scala-2.10

The documentation for [`@inline`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.inline) states:

> An annotation on methods that requests that the compiler should try especially hard to inline the annotated method.

However, unlike the similar [`@tailrec`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.tailrec) annotation, the compiler does not (by default) offer any information about whether or not it managed to inline a method.

**Is there any way to determine if the compiler managed to inline an annotated method?**

Specifically, I'd like for the compiler to tell me, for example, that in all reasonable cases it will be able to inline a method I marked. (Some situtations I can think of where it would warn me that it cannot inline a method is if it is not `final`, and hence requires a vtable lookup if the class is subclassed)

Related questions:

- [When should I (and should I not) use Scala's @inline annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593710/when-should-i-and-should-i-not-use-scalas-inline-annotation/4594718#4594718)
- [Does the @inline annotation in Scala really help performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709095/does-the-inline-annotation-in-scala-really-help-performance)

Comment: I guess compiling with `-Yinline-warnings` is not what you're looking for?

Comment: Possibly, why don't you add an answer explaining what `-Yinline-warnings` does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to remember that Scalac will only try to inline things when you compile with `-optimise` (or `-Yinline` I think).

Consider the following simple case:

```
class Meep {
  @inline def f(x: Int) = x + 19
}

object Main extends App {
  new Meep().f(23)
}
```

If I compile that with `-optimise`, Scalac will gives me a warning: `there were 1 inliner warnings; re-run with -Yinline-warnings for details`. Now, apart from the grammar giggle, this didn't give me much.

So let's recompile with `-Yinline-warnings`. Now I get: `At the end of the day, could not inline @inline-marked method f`. Uh, OK, that was not very helpful either, but I guess that's what I get for using a private compiler flag. :) Some of the inline warnings are a tiny bit more helpful, by the way - like: `Could not inline required method f because bytecode unavailable.` (which happens in the REPL)

The compiler help explains `-Yinline-warnings` as `Emit inlining warnings. (Normally surpressed due to high volume)`, so I guess it has to be used on a case-by-case basis.

Anyway, if we change the definition of `f` in the above snippet to `@inline final def f(x: Int) = x + 19`, the inline warning will go away and the method will be properly inlined.

Hope that helped a bit.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you happen to know a full reference to ALL scala compiler options?

Comment: In the shell you can get information about all the supported options with `scalac -help`, the advanced options with `scalac -X` and the "private" options with `scalac -Y`.

Comment: Heh, I'm embarrassed to say I didn't know that. I suppose that's what I get for primarily using an IDE for all my scala tasks, including compilation.